# Rails routes default action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My rails is 4.1.4, and I have a controller which path is

```
\app\api\mem\inbox_controller.rb
```

this controller is

```
class Mem::InboxController < ApiController  
  def index
      render "OK"
  end  
end
```

my route is

```
scope '/api/' do
  match ":controller(/:id)(/:action)",:via =>['get','post'],id: /\d+/
end
```

So I can visit `/api/mem/inbox/index` ,but when I visit `/api/mem/inbox` I got this error

> The action 'inbox' could not be found for MemController

Actually, if we did not assign the `action`, the action is `index`, but this rule is seemed to not work when the controller is put in the subfolder.

So what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: You may need one more scoped route for the sub folder controllers - `scope '/api/mem/' do`

Comment: thanks,maybe this will work,but I don't want to add an extra route.

Comment: Because I have many subfolder like this,so I have to add many routes

Comment: Try this `scope '/api/(:folder)/' do`

Comment: thank you, but it did't work

Comment: What was the error? May be you need to rename your controller to `Api::Mem::InboxController`

Comment: oh,not work,and is the same error